# Raytune sent message larger than max error python

Tags: grpc, rpc, ray

I am trying to use raytune for hyperparameter tunning via python script and run on an EC2 instance.  However, I am receiving this error.  How do I get around this and increase the max size that can be sent?

```
ray. exceptions. RpcError: Sent message larger than max (631853721 vs.
536870912)
```